# Send img file to server dynamically with jQuery and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I'm trying to make it so that upon submission of an image, the image is saved to the server with CodeIgniter and then displayed on the front end via jquery.

HTML:

```
<form id="set" method="post" action="<?php echo $base_url; ?>schedule/sample" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">

    <img id="result" src="" width="50" height="50" alt="sample" style="display:hidden;"/>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("#file").change(function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var full = base_url +'public/img/'+ file.name;

    $.ajax({  
        type:'POST',  
        url:base_url +'schedule/sample',  
        data:'file='+ file,
        success: function() {
           $('#result').attr('href', full);
           $('#result').fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });
});
```

PHP (Schedule controller):

```
 public function __construct() {       
        parent:: __construct();

        $base_url = $this->config->base_url();

        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('paypal_model');

        $config['upload_path'] = 'public/img/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000';
        $config['max_width'] = '1024';
        $config['max_height'] = '768';

        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('file');
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->load->library('session');
}

    public function sample() {  
        $image = $this->input->post('file');
        $base_url = $this->config->base_url();

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) {    
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            echo 'not uploaded';
        } else {
            $pic = $this->upload->data();
            print_r($pic);

            write_file('public/img/'.$fb_id.'.jpg', $img_data);
            $img = $pic['image_width'];

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

File upload is not supported by AJAX (I think that I what you meant by jQuery). You can use methods like the "hidden iframe file upload" method (google for it, there are many tutorials) to upload files AJAX-like.

The you have to create another controller in CI, which will return image data, or upload the images in a public directory (only if applicable!).

If you use a controller, simply set the appropriate content-type header (e. g. Content-Type: image/png;) and echo the content {get_file_contents} of the image file.

Also, you can do if you want to: 
set the src attribute of the target image element from the iframe where the file is "uploaded".